# Fragment shader interprets all alpha values as 1

Tags: java, lwjgl

When I have a texture that has transparency (and an alpha channel), the transparent areas seem to be coming through as vec4s with values (0, 0, 0, 1).  It's easy enough to discard any color coming through that has an alpha value of 0 (apparently the 0 is still there...).  But this is also causing problems with transparency between 0 and 1.  Everything just shows up fully opaque and I can't for the life of my imagine what is causing it.

Here's what my shader looks like.  I've been playing with it quite a bit, but this is currently the one I'm dealing with.  Just putting through alpha values always a 0.5f, to see what happens.  Still fully opaque:

```
#version 150 core

uniform sampler2D sampler;

in vec4 pass_Color;
in vec2 pass_TextureCoord;
in float pass_alpha;

out vec4 frag_Color;

void main(void) {
    frag_Color = pass_Color;

    vec3 color = texture2D(sampler, pass_TextureCoord);

    frag_Color = vec4(color, pass_alpha);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know lwjgl, but seeing it is based on opengl, you may have to enable [Blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending). Assuming the pass_alpha is calculated correctly in the vertex shader.

Also, the first line in main doesn't do anything becaus frag_color is overwritten in the last line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think you're right, but can you explain to me how to do this? If you will just indulge me, I've been looking all morning.  How does the glEnablei() function work?  I can't find an example of it in use anywhere.  Where do I call it and what do I use as parameters, aside from GL_BLEND?

Comment: You only need glEnablei if you draw to multiple buffers (where the second parameter is the name of the buffer). To enable blending for all just use glEnable(GL_BLEND).

Comment: You magnificent bastard.  Thank you.